# Unable to redirect from a subdomain (and mask the change in the browser address bar) using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi I have seen many examples of this question here on SO and elsewhere but none seem to work in my case. Possibly it's because of the awkward way my hosting company sets up sub-domains on the same level as the root of the main site, so you have

> whatever/htdocs (main document root of www.example.com here)

and also

> whatever/china.example.com/htdocs (china.example.com's root here)

On the main root I have a .htaccess file that does all the usual things like creating a canonical form of the name. On the sub-domain root I have the following .htaccess file which redirects from the sub-domain (called 'china') to the main www root, and to the specific sub-folder it needs to point to.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^china\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/lang/chinese/$1 [R=301]
```

This works fine - except it changes the address in the browser bar to reflect that fact that we're no longer using the sub-domain name - it gives the full www name and the path used. I know it's possible to change that, but every 'text book' example of how to do that I've tried fails. Anyone have a clue about this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried without sending a redirect to the browser, that is, removing `[R=301]`?

Comment: Hi Greg. Thanks for the suggestion. No I hadn't, so I just did. Nothing changed. It still redirected and it still changed the address in the browser bar.